# PHP Get '+' symbol

Tags: php, get, special-characters

Hello fine citizens of Stack Overflow.

I'm currently using PHP for a website and when I use Get for "c++" the get method seems to strip the ++ and I don't get the results I was looking for.

The Page that sends the data($row['Category'] = C++):

```
<a href=\"portfolio_category.php?Category=".$row['Category']."    
\">".$row['Category']."</a>
```

The page that receives the Data:

```
if($category = htmlspecialchars($_GET['Category']))
```

This isn't a huge issue, I can just get rid of the "++" but I would like to know if there's a solution to this, if anyone could help me I'd be much obliged.

Comment: Like many other characters `&,?` etc... `+` has a meaning in a URL.  Try `urlencode($row['Category'])`

Answer (score -3):

You have to encode your string, because the `+` is an url special character. The following code should do the trick:

`urlencode($row['Category'])`

Comment: stop copying comments.